# Overall Sound Volume

Tags: sound-design, sound, mixing, levels, volume

Hey guys, that's maybe a noob question but: What level of overall output control you're using when your producing? I heard that some people use 100/100 in OS, some say that you should bring that level down till it is sounding comfortable.For myself, I'm trying to stay on 50/100.So what's right and what's wrong ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this explanation of monitor calibration: http://www.dynamicinterference.com/blog/2010/09/quick-and-dirty-monitor-calibration/